# Haskell hedgehog-fn custom function generator

Tags: haskell, haskell-hedgehog

When using [hedgehog-fn](https://github.com/qfpl/hedgehog-fn) is it possible to create function generators that generate functions meeting a specific criteria?

For example: would it be possible to have a function generator that only generates bijective functions?

Answer (score 1):

Generating random functions is a hard task still. `hedgehog-fn` can't do much at the moment, see this issue:

- https://github.com/qfpl/hedgehog-fn/issues/3

From my experience, if you need to test against specific functions, it's better to define several functions manually and then choose one randomly.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you for the info, I'll wait to see if there's not anyone else that might come with a solution to this